# Problem with ternary conditional in xml with data-binding

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding

I have the 2 following situation around this button with some params being set by data-binding and I've found that the problem is about a ternary operation with the true and false results order.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tbIbArrowBack"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/extra_large_size_32"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/extra_large_size_32"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_default_medium_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
    android:onClick="@{() -> manager.onClick()}"
    android:visibility="@{manager.showBackButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE,  default=gone}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

1. this code won't copile: `android:background="@{manager.backButtonColor == 0 ? manager.backButtonColor: @drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp,default=@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp}`
2. this code compile:`android:background="@{manager.backButtonColor != 0 ? @drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp : manager.backButtonColor, default=@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp}"`

the item 1 and 2 are how I tried to do a customizable background. While `@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp` is in second position of ternary operation it won't work, but while it is in first position of ternary operation it work. Can someone explain to me why 1 won't compile?

Comment: How do you know your databinding isn't just using the `default` in both cases? I believe you can only assign a background via a resource id value at compilation - to use `android:background` at runtime, you will need to supply a `Drawable`. Or, you can use a `BindingAdapter`

Comment: @PPartisan you are right about the drawable, my code was only working with defaults

Comment: Think the `default=gone` looks strange, because a ternary operation has no `default` value, it is `boolean`... the default value generally is the default value in the view-model.

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of "manager.backButtonColor"? I think you are using 2 different data type for the binding.

Comment: it was part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Could you just try out like this

```
@{data.isSelectMessage ? @drawable/ic_menu_message_selected : @drawable/ic_menu_message_deselected}
```

because it perfectly works for me and I used it like this.

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/img_menu_message"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:alpha="@{alpha}"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:src="@{data.isSelectMessage ? @drawable/ic_menu_message_selected : @drawable/ic_menu_message_deselected}"
       tools:src="@drawable/ic_menu_message_selected" />
```